# Array mean iteration

Tags: python, arrays, iteration

My question pertains to array iteration but is a bit more complicated. You see I have an array with a shape of (4, 50). What I want to do is find the mean of the arrays. I will show a simple explanation of what I mean

`A = np.array([[10,5,3],[12,6,6],[9,8,7],[20,3,4]])`

When this code is run, you get an array with a shape of (4,3). What I want is for the mean of each row to be found and returned.
Returned should be an array of `([[6],[8],[8],[9]])` with the same rows and naturally a column of 1.

Please explain the code and thought process behind it. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: Voila! All code explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [numpy.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) function. Parameter `axis=1` means that the row-wise mean will be calculated. Parameter `keepdims=True` means that original array dimensions are kept.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[10,5,3],[12,6,6],[9,8,7],[20,3,4]])

B = np.mean(A, axis=1, keepdims=True)

print(B)
# Output:
# [[6.]
#  [8.]
#  [8.]
#  [9.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use np.mean and list comprehension into a new array:

```
A = np.array([[10,5,3],[12,6,6], [9,8,7],[20,3,4]])

# Use .reshape() to get 4 rows by 1 column.
new_A = np.array([np.mean(row) for row in A]).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[6.], [8.], [8.], [9.]])
```